# Reading large number of files and merging them in the shell

Tags: shell-script

I am reading values of different variables from a SLHA file and putting value of each variable in a dedicated file using shell script. I have around 50 such variables so 50 data files are generated. A portion of the code is given below-

```
 grep "        25" SPheno.spc|head -1|awk {'print $2'} >> mh.out
 grep "   1000001" SPheno.spc|head -1|awk {'print $2'} >> mdl.out
 grep "   2000001" SPheno.spc|head -1|awk {'print $2'} >> mdr.out
 grep "   1000002" SPheno.spc|head -1|awk {'print $2'} >> mul.out
 grep "   2000002" SPheno.spc|head -1|awk {'print $2'} >> mur.out
 .
 .
 .
```

I want to merge all of these `.out` files from the shell itself in a single grand file such that there are separate columns for each variable in the combined file. I tried to use c++ but opeing such large number of files does not appear efficient.

Comment: You call `grep`, `head` and `awk` 50 times each instead of calling `awk` once? And you are worried about efficiency...?

Answer (score 0):

```
cat m*.out >combined_file.out
```

Comment: I want separate columns for each variable in the combined file. This command will just put everything in a single column.

Comment: @solphy101 And would you claim that a reasonable reader can take this from your question?

Comment: Let me edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
paste m*.out > combined_file
```